# How do I combine branches and flat directories with git p4?

Tags: git, git-p4

How do I get a git directory structure that has both flat directories and branches using git-p4?

Flat directories are directories that have never been branched. We have a some directories that have branches as well as regular directories in the same location.

```
//depot/main/doc
//depot/main/trunk/project
//depot/main/branches/project-v1
//depot/main/branches/project-v2
```

branhces/project-v1 and -v2 are branches from trunk/project. I can arrange to get those branches attached as branches using --detect-branches.

Or I can get the entire directory structure with no branches (without using --detect-branches).

Specifically, I would also like to see:

```
main/doc
main/trunk/project
```

where project would change from branch to branch.

Comment: git doesn't work that way - a git branch covers the entire repository. You could either duplicate doc inside each branch of project, or have doc in a different repository.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid git doesn't work that way - branches cover all the files in a repository.

Your choices are:

1. Duplicate doc inside each branch of project, and maintain separately.
2. Put doc within its own repository.

In the second case you can still end up with a directory structure you want:

```
doc/.git  ## Doc repository
project/.git  ## Project repository with whatever branch you want checked out
```

Or you could use [git submodules](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) to embed the doc repository inside a project repository.